# Função validar cadastro usuários

Tags: php, mysql, orientação-a-objetos, funções, foreach

Estou começando em OO no php, e com a função abaixo estou tentando verificar se o nome vindo do formulário é igual a algum valor vindo da minha tabela de usuários antes de fazer insert na tabela. Gostaria de que alguém pudesse me dar uma luz já que nenhuma das tentativas deu certo até agora e essa é a mais próxima que consegui.

```
    public function validarDadosUsuario($validaNome) {
        require('conexao.php');
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        $dados = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        foreach ($dados as $row) {

            foreach ($row as $indice => $value) {

                if($row[$indice] == $validaNome) {
                    echo 'Nomes iguais';
                    $this->$validaNome = true;
                    break;

                } else {
                    echo 'Nomes diferentes';
                    $this->validaNome = false;
                }
            }

        }

        return $validaNome;
    }
```

$usuario = new Usuario($_POST['add_nome'], $_POST['add_email'], $_POST['add_tipo'], $_POST['add_senha']);

$usuario->validarDadosUsuario($_POST['add_nome']);

Comment: só com esses dados não conseguimos ajudar

Answer (score 1):

Se a função for somente para validar o Nome, você poderia já fazer o select na tabela usando o valor passado por `$_POST['add_nome']` e a partir disso é só você fazer o tratamento usando if caso o select retorne True ou False.

Mais ou menos desse jeito:

```
$usuario = new Usuario($_POST['add_nome'], $_POST['add_email'], $_POST['add_tipo'], $_POST['add_senha']);
$usuario->validarDadosUsuario($_POST['add_nome']);

public function validarDadosUsuario($validaNome) {
        require('conexao.php');
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE nomeDacoluna = '$validaNome'"; //A condição WHERE pra buscar os dados na tabela
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        //Retorna o número de linhas do resultado do select
        $retorno = $result->rowCount();

        //Verificando se o select retornou algum resultado;
        if($retorno != 0):
            echo 'Já existe esse Nome (Nome Repetido)';
        exit;
        else:
            echo 'Não Existe esse Nome (Nome Novo)';
        exit;
        endif;
    }
```

Comment: Olá Jonatas bom dia, muito obrigado pela explicação, era isso que eu queria fazer, não tinha pensado em já trazer da minha consulta o dado que eu gostaria de comparar. a minha dúvida é a seguinte, eu posso agora dentro do bloco if caso o nome seja diferente chamar a minha função de cadastar os dados no banco? (que já está funcionando) e caso seja igual adicionar um die() e devolver uma mensagem de erro?

Comment: Sim, dentro do if você pode colocar o código de acordo com o que você precisa fazer.
Faz o teste, e se funcionar avisa aqui.

Comment: Olá Jonatas, fiz o teste e deu certo, porém estou tendo problemas com namspace no meu código de cadastro, estou recebendo o seguinte erro ao usar meu arquivo que valida os dados para cadastrar: Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement or after any declare call in the script. Já verifiquei e a declaração do namespace está no inicio do script, por favor se pudesse dar uma olhada no meu código eu agradeço, ainda não achei uma solução. https://github.com/wildrove/projeto_biblioteca

Comment: No seu arquivo validar_login.php tem uma linha em branco logo no começo do arquivo antes da tag '<?php' remove este espaço e faça o teste. Creio eu que o motivo desse erro seja justamente por isso. Lembrando que se funcionar deixa um ok aqui pra mim saber se consegui te ajudar.

Comment: Olá Jonatas, realmente eu havia removido somente o espaço da linha onde se encontrava o namespace, a linha acima da tag do php eu não tinha removido.Obrigado!